# Tensorflow: Unable to visualize jpeg images

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I used the a script similar to the one [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_imagenet_data.py) to convert my dataset to sharded tfrecords. But when I attempt to read it using script below tensorflow freezes and I have to kill the process using kill. (Note: Right now I am working in CPU mode)

```
    def parse_example_proto(example_serialized):
    feature_map = {
      'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,
                                          default_value=''),
      'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], dtype=tf.int64,
                                              default_value=-1),
      'image/class/text': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,
                                             default_value=''),
  }

    features = tf.parse_single_example(example_serialized, feature_map)

    init_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(features['image/encoded'], channels = 3)
    init_image.set_shape([800,480,3])
    image = tf.reshape(init_image,tf.pack([800, 480, 3]))
    float_image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
    label = tf.cast(features['image/class/label'], dtype=tf.int32)

    return float_image , label, features['image/class/text']


def batch_inputs(batch_size, train,sess, num_preprocess_threads=4,
                 num_readers=1):

    with tf.name_scope('batch_processing'):
        tf_record_pattern = os.path.join('/home/raarora/', '%s-*' % 'train')
        data_files = tf.gfile.Glob(tf_record_pattern)
        if data_files is None:
            raise ValueError('No data files found for this dataset')
#        print data_files
        # Create filename_queue
        if train:
            filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(data_files,
                                                          shuffle=True,
                                                          capacity=8)
        else:
            filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(data_files,
                                                          shuffle=False,
                                                          capacity=1)

        reader =tf.TFRecordReader()
        _, example_serialized = reader.read(filename_queue)

        image, label, _ = parse_example_proto(example_serialized)

        examples_per_shard = 201
        min_queue_examples = examples_per_shard * 2

        images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [image, label], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=4,
            capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size,
            min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
        print images.eval(session=sess)
        return s,images,labels


if __name__ == '__main__':

    sess = tf.Session()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    s,_,_  = batch_inputs(2,1,sess)
```

Comment: Here's a bug filed which may relate to same issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6702, anyone has any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve this. I thought TFRecord is sort of dictionary and you need to give only the keys required, but upon giving the entire feature map along with small changes to how image was processed later, it worked.

Another mistake I made was that queue_runner should be started after calling tf.train.shuffle_batch(). I dont know if it's a bug or a gap in my understanding

Here's the working code for reading the data

```
def getImage(filename):
    # convert filenames to a queue for an input pipeline.
    filenameQ = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename],num_epochs=None)

    # object to read records
    recordReader = tf.TFRecordReader()

    # read the full set of features for a single example 
    key, fullExample = recordReader.read(filenameQ)

    # parse the full example into its' component features.
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        fullExample,
        features={
            'image/height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/colorspace': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,default_value=''),
            'image/channels':  tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),            
            'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64),
            'image/class/text': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,default_value=''),
            'image/format': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,default_value=''),
            'image/filename': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,default_value=''),
            'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value='')
        })


    # now we are going to manipulate the label and image features

    label = features['image/class/label']
    image_buffer = features['image/encoded']

    # Decode the jpeg
    with tf.name_scope('decode_jpeg',[image_buffer], None):
        # decode
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_buffer, channels=3)

        # and convert to single precision data type
        image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)


    # cast image into a single array, where each element corresponds to the greyscale
    # value of a single pixel. 
    # the "1-.." part inverts the image, so that the background is black.
    # re-define label as a "one-hot" vector 
    # it will be [0,1] or [1,0] here. 
    # This approach can easily be extended to more classes.
    image=tf.reshape(image,[height,width,3])
    label=tf.pack(tf.one_hot(label-1, nClass))

    return label, image


label, image = getImage("train-00000-of-00001")
imageBatch, labelBatch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [image, label], batch_size=2,
    capacity=20,
    min_after_dequeue=10)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
# start the threads used for reading files
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess,coord=coord)
batch_xs, batch_ys = sess.run([imageBatch, labelBatch])
print batch_xs

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

Note: I wasnt clear about sharded records so I used just one shard.

Credits to https://agray3.github.io/2016/11/29/Demystifying-Data-Input-to-TensorFlow-for-Deep-Learning.html